# multiple validatiors for a textbox in a gridview footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, gridview

I have a textbox in a GridView footer template. The requirements are the textbox has to be numeric, greater than 0  and limits to 2 decimal places. I have following three validators for this text box.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label_Amount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Amount") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAmount" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Amount is a required field"
            ControlToValidate="txtAmount" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Insert">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvAmount" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Amount must be &gt; 0"
            ControlToValidate="txtAmount" ValueToCompare="0" ValidationGroup="Insert" Text="*"
            Type="Double" Operator="GreaterThan">
        </asp:CompareValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revAmount" ControlToValidate="txtAmount" ValidationGroup="Insert" Text="*"
            runat="server" ErrorMessage="Amount limits to two decimal places" ValidationExpression="^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$">
        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The problem is if I put 12,3, I only want to see the error message of "Amount must be >0". However I got two error messages instead. The third regular express validator is fired too. I am not sure why? I wonder how do I solve this? Can I write a regular express to combine my three requirements together? I also tried to use CustomeValidator, but somehow the JavaScript function never gets called. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you programming for html5 (.Net 4.5+)?

Comment: I asked the above because if you are then you can eliminate all the asp.net validation with `<input type="number" pattern="<regexp as desired>" min=".01" required /> `

Answer (score 1):

The `revAmount` validation fails for `12,3` or for `abc` because these strings don't match the regular expression. If you want that validator to fire only when a number does not have 1 or 2 decimal places, it must consider that a non-numeric string is "valid" (leaving the detection of that case to `cvAmount`, as you indicate in your question).

The following regular expression can be used for `revAmount`. It matches non-numeric strings in addition to the cases matched by your original expression:

```
ValidationExpression="^(((?!^\d+\.?\d*$).)*|\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)$"
```

N.B. I kept your original validation, which fails for numbers like `123.` (ending on the decimal point). You may consider modifying the error message to account for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a ValidationSummary control somewhere in your page.

[Please see an example here](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/10/validationsummary-example-how-to-use.html)

Comment: Maybe I am not so clear in my post, but I did have ValidationSummary right after the GridView.